# How can I get item by row from SQL and make to String

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce, tooltip

I have a SQL Server CE database with following desc:

```
Key TypeName    nvarchar(230)   460 No  No
    ID_FK   int 4   No  No
    Type    nvarchar(150)   300 No  No
    Description nvarchar(1000)  2000    No  Yes
    Syntax  nvarchar(2500)  5000    No  Yes
    BaseType    nvarchar(500)   1000    No  Yes
```

using:

```
tablename: tb_CSType
 SqlCeConnection con;
 SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
 DataSet dsType = new DataSet();
 SqlCeCommand selectCommand;
```

and I got a tooltip that has the following syntax:

> KeywordTipTexts.Add("", ""); //compose of strings

that I want to be something like:

> KeywordTipTexts.Add(TypeName, Syntax);

now for question how can i get the data of tables according to its row and make it toString .

like this:

```
KeywordTipTexts.Add(TypeName, Syntax);
```

but must convert to string .

hope you can help me .thanks a lot in advance . more power!
//please tell me if something you cant understand in my Q ill try to update .

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SqlCeDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class to read the results and use `Convert.ToString()` to convert it to string (duh! :p).

```
SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
String typeName;
String syntax;
if(reader.Read()) {
    typeName = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["typeName"]) ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["typeName "]);
    syntax = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["syntax"]) ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["syntax "]);
}
KeywordTipTexts.Add(typeName, syntax);
reader.Close();
```

Something like that...

Comment: command doesnt exist i already include this:
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

but still it doesnt exist

Comment: @Elegiac, if you can, please try installing this MS SQL Server Compact http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876 and reference the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` under **Program Files > Microsoft SQL Server Compact > v4.0 > Desktop**. After that, you should be able to use it in your project.

Comment: I only understood your question just now. :S **`command`** is a variable of class `SqlCeCommand`. You have to declare it along with other dependent classes like `SqlConnection` to be able to execute a successful command.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your problem:

```
string conStr = @"Data Source=PathAndNameOFSdfFile.sdf";
SqlCeDataReader sqldrAllData;
SqlCeConnection sqlCon = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);

SqlCeCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand("Select TypeName, Syntax From tb_CsType", sqlCon);
sqlCon.Open();
sqldrAllData = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

while(sqldrAllData.Read())
{
    KeywordTipTexts.Add(sqldrAllData["TypeName"].ToString(), sqldrAllData["Syntax"].ToString());
}

sqlCon.Close();
```